# Model::save() returns false even though all data saved correctly

Tags: database, cakephp

I want to update some field in table Scale. I have an array:

```
$s = array(
   'id' => '1',
   'name' => 'NAME',
   'description' => 'DESCRIPTION',
   'type' => 'custom'
);
```

and saving it like this:

```
$this->Scale->save($s);
```

I received an error without any notofication. It's not the validation problem, because I have no validation in this model. Even though I have an error, all data saved correctly.

So why save method returns false?

Comment: There's no formal error. Just when I check in if statement that data has been saved correctly - it returns me FALSE

Comment: could you show your if statement as well..

Comment: `if( $this->Scale->save($s) ) throw new NotSaveException();`

Comment: You say the data is saved correctly.  I assume you mean that you see it appear in the database? Is this right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Also Cake changed `modified` field correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going by the comments you have your `if` structured incorrectly.

```
<?php
if ($this->Scale->save($s)) {
    throw new NotSaveException();
}
```

`$this->Scale->save()` will return `true` which will in turn throw the exception.  You need the exception in the `else` block

The `if` block should be...

```
<?php
if ($this->Scale->save($s)) {
    // deal with success
} else {
    throw new NotSaveException();
}
```

Comment: WOW ... I forgot to put ``!` to the statement: if (!$this->Scale->save($s))`. Thanks ! :D

Comment: @Ziemo, that's the reason to include all the *relevant* code when asking a question :)